# Mysql needs more than 12 hours to read 1 GB of XML file with 2 columns per line

Tags: mysql

I've done as the mysql manual suggested.
I needed 2 columns exported from one DB to another.

So I made an XML export of those 2 columns, I split it into about 1 GB small files.

Now I tried to parse them on the target server (quite a strong AWS server).

```
Query   47739   reading file    LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/data/cold/xml/experience100.xml' IGNORE INTO table history  0.000
```

It is stuck since 47700 seconds "reading" a file.
It can be read in a minute!
I think I could parse that in qbasic in an hour.

```
nvme2n1           0.37        46.93         0.00       2816          0
```

It is reading the XML file at 50 kb/second. I would have expected 100mb/sec

version is mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.14-MariaDB

**Update:**
I made a test and removed most lines from the file.
It works fine (at 50kb/second...)

The problem is the parsing speed, not the file content.

Comment: Looking at the MariaDB knowledge base, the IGNORE clause needs a number of lines to ignore and you may need to define row names if they aren't the same between the XML file and the table. My guess is that IGNORE without a count ignores all lines.

Comment: I've tried it without IGNORE too.
Also it worked on a small file, didn't ignore the lines.

It would also not explain why the READ rate on my disk is at only 50 kb/sec.
It means the parser is working at 50kb/sec which is ridiculously slow.

Even a gameboy might do it at that rate.

Comment: if the xml file has any schema or other attributes refer to external resources, then maria may be doing network lookups.

Comment: Nothing like that inside, I checked it.
Except that: xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
It's what mysql outputs with mysql -X

Comment: Is the XML all valid and can be parsed with lxml or other command line parsers? Also on the system side, try increasing read buffer size. Another suggestion is to parse it externally and batch write, which should be much faster as a individual INSERT processes are expensive.

Comment: Well, would be funny if mysql generates wrong XML right ?
And yes, I solved it by writing a parser.
As the internal parser wasn't fit for the job.

Comment: XML is probably a good intermediate format for going between two different database server types, however if both are MySQL, the plain SQL version of the `mysqldump` is probably sufficient.